# C# gets previously loaded values of text fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a pretty odd problem. I was working on an item editing page end encountered some odd bug, that ASP passess old values to C# `.cs` code.

In my `Page_Load`

```
private int SomeID = 0;
if (!IsPostBack) {
    ...
    SomeID = Convert.ToInt32(Page.RouteData.Values["id"])
    LoadFunction();
}
```

Loading function:

```
DataBaseDataContext db = new DataBaseDataContext();
var Item = db.FirstOrDefault(k => k.ID == SomeID);

NameTextBox.Text = Item.Name;
PriceTextBox.Text = Item.Price.ToString();
```

Saving function:

```
DataBaseDataContext db = new DataBaseDataContext();
var Item = db.FirstOrDefault(k => k.ID == SomeID);

Item.Name = NameTextBox.Text;
Item.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceTextBox.Text);
...
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I was bothering, why it doesn't save changes for me, so I set breakpoint in `db.SubmitChanges()` in the saving function (loading works fine). But when I looked up in value preview in VisualStudio, it showed me that it wants to send previously loaded values and not those I edited in my form.

I must be missing something, as it works in other places of my code, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: What does your Page_Load look like?

Comment: What does `NameTextBox.Text` show when you hit the breakpoint? old or edited value ?

Comment: In your `Saving function` the `NameTextBox.Text and PriceTextBox.Text` is showing you new values or old values plz check..

Comment: from your edit it looks like SomeID is correct when loading but it is  zero when saving

Comment: use `static int SomeID;` instead of `private int SomeID = 0;`..

Comment: It trully was 0... I moved it outside as you both suggested and set it as static and it worked - thanks! But I need it to be a post to accept it

Comment: i have updated this logic into my answer plz check.

Comment: setting it to static is incorrect because it will be shared accross all requests  - you will have problem when you get requests from multiple clients with different SomeID value. Correct way is to set it in page load but outside the !ISPostBack condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Page.Ispostback` Property Into your `Page_Load` event like

```
//Page_Load Event
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         DataBaseDataContext db = new DataBaseDataContext();
         var Item = db.FirstOrDefault(k => k.ID == SomeID);

         NameTextBox.Text = Item.Name;
         PriceTextBox.Text = Item.Price.ToString();  
    }
```

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Instead of `private` in `private int SomeID = 0` use `static`,if will hold your old primary value and solve your problem as well.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I have my loading function wrapped in (!IsPostBack), and my saving f. is called from a button

Comment: but in your loading function there is no `!IsPostBack`.

Answer (score 2):

Set SomeID outside !IsPostback

Answer (score 1):

Check if on `PostBack` in `Page_Load` you are NOT setting values to those `TextBox`es again.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   DataBaseDataContext db = new DataBaseDataContext();
   var Item = db.FirstOrDefault(k => k.ID == SomeID);

   NameTextBox.Text = Item.Name;
   PriceTextBox.Text = Item.Price.ToString();  
}
```

Comment: I have my loading function wrapped in (!IsPostBack), and my saving f. is called from a button